# Unable to connect Ubuntu 12.04 to a projector using the vga port

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, projector

Whenever I try to connect my Lenovo G570 with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit to a Projector, it gets detected, but the display on both, the projector and on my laptop keep blinking continuously making it unusable. Even the focus of the screen shift from one workspace, that is, i am able to view two halves of workspaces.

Laptop Specifications:
2nd Gen Core i3, 4GB RAM, AMD Radeon Graphics

I have ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (`**experimental**` beta) installed, but the status displays: "This driver is activated but not currently in use."

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Should I remove it and try finding some alternative driver?
Is there any software to correct it?
Or is it a completely different problem??

I face the issue with the Unity environment. I have GNOME environment also installed but i haven't tried connecting using it. I'll try that and update on the question.

Comment: Can you try the projector (and its VGA cable) on another PC?

Comment: @K7AAY u mean another pc with ubuntu? Its my college's projector, and all lab's pcs have windows, even my friends' laptops got windows.. they all work fine with the projector..

Comment: Try `Super+P`. May it fix your problem.(in my case it worked as I was also facing a little bit different problem with projector)

Comment: @guruprasad i should use `Super+p` after connecting the projector?

Comment: @K7AAY I read at another [link](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/473028/ubuntu-13-cant-connect-to-projector) while searching, and he had a similar problem - connecting to projector after boot, no luck, but connecting to projector before booting works..only the resolution changes to 1280*768 from 1366*768. i tried it and it works the same with me!

Comment: There's your answer -  post it in a day or two and then check it off as the answer to boost your points score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to (not permanently, but still) solve the problem.

Neither the VGA nor the HDMI cables work when connecting an already booted machine to the projector.

When connecting the projector via VGA, before boot, it still fails to produce a proper working screen through the projector. Here is the [link](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/473028/ubuntu-13-cant-connect-to-projector), where I got the idea to connect before boot.

However, connecting via HDMI cable to the projector, before booting the system, not only solves the problem of getting a working screen, but also solves another problem, that of resolution. I am able to work on full resolution (1366*768) instead of having to scale down to 1280*768 (or 4:3 basically).

The issue with the VGA cable connectivity still persists.